# Docker+Jboss, port mapping

Tags: docker, jboss

I deployed application to docker.
JBoss `standelone.xml` contains line:

```
<socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
```

My docker file contains:

```
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/jboss/jboss-eap-6.1/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

My `run.sh` looks like:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -it --rm my_build/jboss-eap:6.1.1
```

When I start application I can not find jBoss home page on `localhost:8080`. Why it wasn't exposed?

Comment: Is your container running (docker ps). Normally you don't need ':' after `EXPOSE`

Comment: Sorry, it was my typo in question not in Dockerfile

Comment: your issue is most probably in the jboss configuration, ensure you can telnet / wget on localhost:8080 in the container before you further debug the   port-expose. The way you run docker is correct, so there is most probably an issue either in the container or port 8080 is already used on your host

Comment: @EugenMayer, thanks for answer! You are right, the issue was in bizarre standalone settings:   `port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:1000}` so the correct port was `9080`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your issue is most probably in the jboss configuration, ensure you can telnet / wget on localhost:8080 in the container before you further debug the   port-expose. The way you run docker is correct, so there is most probably an issue either in the container or port 8080 is already used on your host